# Exception thrown when trying to load Pentaho report through java program

Tags: java, report, pentaho

This code was mostly taken from Pentaho's website on sample programs. The goal is to use their API to generate HTML output with a Pentaho report. 
The report was created with Pentaho 3.5.0-RC2

The version of jars I am using are the following:
pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core-3.5.0-RC2.jar
libloader-1.1.1.jar
libbase-1.1.1.jar

The exception I am getting is the following:

```
org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ContentNotRecognizedException: None of the selected factories was able to handle the given data: ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceLoader, identifier=file:/C:/Users/elias.kopsiaftis/workspace_experimental/TestPentahoReport/bin/Test.prpt, factoryParameters={}, parent=null}
at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.DefaultResourceManagerBackend.create(DefaultResourceManagerBackend.java:295)
at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:387)
at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:342)
at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.createDirectly(ResourceManager.java:205)
at ReportTester.getReportDefinition(ReportTester.java:74)
at ReportTester.getReport(ReportTester.java:25)
at ReportTester.main(ReportTester.java:84)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ReportTester.getReport(ReportTester.java:26)
at ReportTester.main(ReportTester.java:84)
```

And finally, the code snippet!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.*;

import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.DataFactory;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.MasterReport;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportProcessingException;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.table.html.HtmlReportUtil;
import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.Resource;
import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.util.StackableException;
import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceException;
import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager;

public class ReportTester {
    private String reportName = "FormCompleteUsagePerPartnerByMonth.prpt";
    private String reportPath = "";


    public void getReport() {
        try {
            final MasterReport report = getReportDefinition();
            report.getParameterValues().put("partner", "");
            report.getParameterValues().put("startingdate", "2015-03-01");
            report.getParameterValues().put("endingdate", "2015-03-05");
            HtmlReportUtil.createStreamHTML(report, System.out);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }



private MasterReport getReportDefinition() {
    try {
        // Using the classloader, get the URL to the reportDefinition file
        final ClassLoader classloader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        final URL reportDefinitionURL = classloader.getResource(reportPath + reportName);

        if(reportDefinitionURL == null) {
            System.out.println("URL was null");
        }
        // Parse the report file
        final ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
        resourceManager.registerDefaults();
        final Resource directly = resourceManager.createDirectly(reportDefinitionURL, MasterReport.class);
        return (MasterReport) directly.getResource();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReportTester rt = new ReportTester();
    rt.getReport();
}




}
```

Any advice on this would be much appreciated as I have been scratching my head on this all day. Thanks in advance!